# how to skip empty rows in csv in using Mulesoft transform message

Tags: xml, csv, mule, transformation, dataweave

I'm getting CSV file as input and want to tranform to XML format. It is creating empty xml records, when I'm getting few empty csv rows or records in input csv file. How to ignore empty records to process  and/or records to create in output xml file.

Using Mule Runtime 4.2.1

CSV Input:

```
Type,AdminAlias,OriginatorID,OriginatorName,TransactionCode,TotalPaymentAmount,TotalClaimsCount,CreatedDateTime,FileDateTime,SourceDocumentType,ReceivedFileName,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
HEADER,GPS,,,,,,2020-04-02T10:55:56,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Type,ActionCode,Status,StatusMessage,RecipientName,ClaimPayeeType,LH1ParticipantUniqueID,ParticipantExternalId,ParticipantEmployeeNumber,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,SSN,DOB,ProviderID,ProviderName,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,AddressLine3,AddressLine4,City,StateCode,ZipCode,CountryCode,ExternalClaimNumber,ClaimAmount,Claim Type,PaidDate,ReceiptReceived,ClaimOnHold,ServiceStartDate,ServiceEndDate,ExpenseCategory,ExpenseType,ServiceCode,ServiceCodeType,ClaimDescription,KeyName,KeyValue,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
CLAIM,I,P,,,,,,,DONALD,,HUGHES,123456789,1990-12-02,123456789,ASSOCIATED OMS AND IMPLANT CEN,,,,,,,,,22007635202,52.80,,,TRUE,FALSE,2000-03-06,2000-03-06,Medical Expenses,Other Medical,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

DataWeave script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere" 
ns ns0 http://www.lighthouse1.com/LH1OnDemand/ClaimsExchange/2008/10/01/ //writeDeclaration = false //skipNullOn = "elements"
---
{
    ns0#LH1StandardClaimsExchange @(TotalPaymentAmount: sum(payload.bodyRecords.ClaimAmount filter ($!="")), AdminAlias: payload.header.AdminAlias , TotalClaimsCount: sizeOf(payload.bodyRecords.ClaimAmount) as String , CreatedDateTime: payload.header.CreatedDateTime): {
        (payload.bodyRecords filter ($ !=null and $ !='') map ((bodyRecord , indexOfBodyRecord) -> {
            Claim @(Status: bodyRecord.Status , ActionCode: bodyRecord.ActionCode): {
                Participant @(FirstName: bodyRecord.FirstName , LastName: bodyRecord.LastName , SSN: bodyRecord.SSN as String , DOB: bodyRecord.DOB as String): '',
                Provider @(ProviderID: bodyRecord.ProviderID , ProviderName: bodyRecord.ProviderName): {
                    MailingAddress @(AddressLine1: bodyRecord.AddressLine1 , City: bodyRecord.City , StateCode: bodyRecord.StateCode , ZipCode: bodyRecord.ZipCode , CountryCode: bodyRecord.CountryCode): ''
                },
                ClaimDetail @(ExternalClaimNumber: bodyRecord.ExternalClaimNumber , ClaimAmount: bodyRecord.ClaimAmount , ReceiptReceived: bodyRecord.ReceiptReceived as String , ClaimOnHold: bodyRecord.ClaimOnHold as String , ServiceStartDate: bodyRecord.ServiceStartDate as String , ServiceEndDate: bodyRecord.ServiceEndDate as String , ExpenseCategory: bodyRecord.ExpenseCategory , ExpenseType: bodyRecord.ExpenseType): ''
            }
        }))
    }
}
```

CSV input

[image]

XML output

[image]

Comment: Please add the files in your question in textual form, and not as link or images.

Comment: Updated my question with input csv and transform message. please check

Answer (score 0):

Would love to take a look, but are you sure the CSV content you shared here is correct?

validate the CSV file you share here --> https://csvlint.io

and

If possible share the Output XML as a textual reference rather than a image or better share the flow.